# When GroupBox with databound children is re-enabled, only first child gets re-enabled

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, groupbox

[image: screen capture of defect]

I have a groupbox with child buttons. All the child buttons have their .Enabled databound to form-level booleans. I also databound the booleans to labels for the sake of troubleshooting. This is a minimal reproduction of a problem I'm having in a larger app.

Disabling the groupbox works fine.

Re-enabling the groupbox does not, as can be seen in the screen capture. Button3 ought to get re-enabled. It doesn't. Why?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged


    Private _canClone As Boolean = True
    Private _canEdit  As Boolean = True


    Public Property CanClone As Boolean
        Get
            Return _canClone
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _canClone = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanClone"))
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Property CanEdit    As Boolean
        Get
            Return _canEdit
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _canEdit = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanEdit"))
        End Set
    End Property



    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged


    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        GroupBox1.Enabled = Not GroupBox1.Enabled
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Button1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Enabled", Me, "CanClone"   , True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
        Button3.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Enabled", Me, "CanEdit"    , True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))

        Label1 .DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text",    Me, "CanClone"   , True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
        Label3 .DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text",    Me, "CanEdit"    , True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Not 100% sure why the GroupBox does that, but since you are using DataBinding, you shouldn't handle this with the GroupBox.Enabled property.  Your click event should just do `CanEdit = Not CanEdit`, and `CanClone = Not CanClone`.

Comment: The group box needs to be disabled regardless so that the user can't interact with it while certain activities are going on. I can do an ugly hack like cacheCanClone = CanClone, disable, re-enable, CanClone = cacheCanClone, but I would only want to do that as a last resort.

Comment: But you have competing forces at play here.  The CanEdit and CanClone properties versus the Parent container.  Both want to influence the Enabled property of the buttons.

Comment: For what it's worth, the same thing happens when you use a Panel in place of the GroupBox.

Comment: Why would that be any different?  It's the same issue.  You will have to re-think how you want to do this.

Comment: I removed the GroupBox altogether in the real project, but the asymmetry of disable versus enable in the example given still warrants a good mechanical explanation.

Comment: You would have to update your code now.  What is the button click doing?